# How to call CheckedChanged(sender,e) from another private method

Tags: vb.net, events, gridview

I have two different functions :

```
Public Sub CB_CheckChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    line of code;
End Sub

Protected Sub GV_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GV.RowDataBound
    line of code;
End Sub
```

I am trying to call `CB_CheckChanged()` inside `GV_RowDataBound()` function.
Can you please tell me, how to call one event into another event.

Note : Checkbox is inside gridview

Comment: If you don't use the `sender` or `e` parameters inside the event you can simply pass null: `CB_CheckedChanged(Nothing, Nothing)`. Though the recommended way would be to move the code inside `CheckedChanged` to a separate method, as you're not supposed to call event handlers directly from your own code.

Answer (score 2):

```
Protected Sub GV_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GV.RowDataBound
    CB_CheckChanged(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
Public Sub CB_CheckChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   line of code;
End Sub

Protected Sub GV_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GV.RowDataBound
  CB_CheckChanged(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub
```

If the event is not handling any task,You can use

```
 Public Sub CB_CheckChanged()
   line of code;
End Sub

Protected Sub GV_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GV.RowDataBound
  CB_CheckChanged()
End Sub
```

Comment: If `CB_CheckedChanged` is bound to an event you should _not_ omit the arguments. Doing so is bad practice and prone to breaking things. Instead, create a separate method that you call _from the `CB_CheckedChanged` event handler_.

Comment: From the OP's code, it is not bound to any event, anyway, I will update my answer.

Comment: He might be using [`AddHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement), otherwise there would be no reason to have the `sender` and `e` parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your help